# How to reopen STDOUT to screen in PHP?

Tags: php, stdout, io-redirection

I‘ve already redirected STDOUT to a file in PHP. Now I want to reopen STDOUT and display output on my screen. The code following doesn't work. How to do it? Thanks!

```
<?php
fclose(STDOUT);
$STDOUT = fopen('file_stdout', 'w');
print 'aaaaaa';
//fclose(STDOUT);
$STDOUT = fopen('/dev/stdout', 'w');
print 'vvvvvv';
```

Comment: `print` by itself does not send the text to whatever file handle you opened last.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/dev/tty` (or the appropriate device file for the OS) instead. `/dev/stdout` points to FD1, which you've already closed.